# Are there any Windows text editors that display fonts smoothly the way Adobe applications do?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, text-editors, word-processing

When I type text into an Adobe application on Windows - Photoshop, Illustrator, Indesign (although not Fireworks) - the text is rendered smoothly and the font appears without any sign of jagged edges.

However, when I type text into any other Windows text editors including Notepad, Wordpad, Notepad++, Microsoft Word, the text appears less smoothly rendered. Why?

I'm looking for a text editor, word processor or note taking application for Windows that renders fonts smoothly as an Adobe application does.

Comment: Can you put up a couple screenshots for comparison?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have turned off Cleartype.